# Don't steal from the Riley community

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

- Steal my prefix and I'll belong.
- Steal my infix and I'll be heavy.
- Steal my suffix and I'll be strong.
- Steal my whole and I'll be gone.

---

*Leave me be, for I am a community.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Could this 'community' be a:

> **TOWN**?

*Steal my prefix and I'll belong.*

> If we remove the first letter (T) we get **OWN** - a word with connotations of something **belonging**.

*Steal my infix and I'll be heavy.*

> Remove the middle W and we get **TON** - a **heavy** weight.

*Steal my suffix and I'll be strong.*

> Remove the last letter (N) and we get **TOW** - an action which can be done by something **strong** (like a tugboat or a truck).

*Steal my whole and I'll be gone.*

> Remove all the letters and you have nothing left!